# npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. Why is this happening? I tried downloading firebase tools but it doesn't work

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, npm-install, firebase-tools

I am trying to set up firebase-tools in my computer but I keep getting errors when trying to do so. I keep getting all these errors when trying to do it:

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\jaiza\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\node_modules\\exegesis',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\jaiza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\exegesis\node_modules\ajv'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\jaiza\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\node_modules\\exegesis\\node_modules\\ajv'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn pwsh.exe
npm ERR! path C:\Users\jaiza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\protobufjs
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn pwsh.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\jaiza\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-26T18_09_18_300Z-debug-0.log
```

I have tried desinstalling and reinstalling my node.js since there seems to be a problem with my npm but nothing works. It keeps saying `npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file` even though I installed everything from the node.js website.

A side note that might be relevant, windows 11 automatically installed about 3 months already having vs code and other programs installed.

I am trying to install firebase to develop my own website but the firebase-tools is not downloading correctly

Answer (score 0):

The file is corrupted and cannot be found for firebase-tools in roaming directory.

Follow the following steps:

1. Delete the node_modules folder from this location `C:\Users\jaiza\AppData\Roaming\npm`
2. Copy the node_modules folder from this location `C:\Program Files\nodejs` to this location `C:\Users\jaiza\AppData\Roaming\npm`
3. Now run the command `npm install -g firebase-tools` in node js command prompt.

Your file will be generated. Hope this should resolve your issue.